# How can I add shared variable to chakram?

Tags: mocha.js, resteasy, restful-url

I'am using [chakram](https://github.com/dareid/chakram) + [mocha](https://mochajs.org/).
How can I use shared variables for all test?

For example, I would like to use variable `API_PATH="http://example.com/v1/"` in tests. And this variable could be changed during running test. So, my test looks like this.

```
var response = chakram.get(API_PATH + "products");
expect(response).to.have.status(200);
```

As example, protractor has `conf.js` with parameter `baseUrl`. Running test looks like protractor `conf.js --baseUrl http://example.com/`

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried so far? Have you tried using `beforeEach` to reinitialize the object that you are using? You could just make the the shared variables declared outside of your tests.

EDIT: Adding details from what Jerry said: 
If you want all variable to be reused within the same test, you must make them global variables. See example below

```
///include dependencies
var assert = require('assert'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    chakram = require('chakram');

//INIT GLOBAL VARAIBLES FOR within the same test
var testObj,
    dummyData = {
        user: 'John Kim',
        lastSeenOnline: 'Wed August 11  12:05 2017'
    };

describe ('#User', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        //init what the object contains
        testObj = new DataStore(data, ContainerStore);
    });

    it ('#Should return the name of the user', function () {
        assert.equal(testObj.get('user'), dummyData.user);
    });

    it("should offer simple HTTP request capabilities", function () {
        return chakram.get("http://httpbin.org/get");
    });
});
```

Note: I work with react but this is an example. We assume that the ContainerStore contains a method that has a method for get() which just gets the value of our JSON object. You can use testObj many time in different describe blocks since it is declared outside of your tests. But you should remember to always reinitialize your tesObj in a `beforeEach()`; otherwise, you risk populating your individual tests. There are cases were you do not have to initialize the beforeEach() and it is optional.

Comment: `You could just make the the shared variables declared outside of your tests.`
My question about this.

Answer (score 0):

For Example in `config.js`

```
module.exports = { 
    "baseUrl": "http://example.com/", 
    "googleUrl":  "http://www.google.com.tr/"
  };
```

And use in javascript code:

```
let config = require('/config'); 

describle("test describle", () => {

   it("test", () => {
      chakram.get(config.baseUrl + "products");   //for example use
   })
})
```